# change width of an element on windows resize with alpine.js

Tags: alpine.js

I used **:resize.window** directive to track windows resize and change an element **width** with style properties but that directive works only one time when alpine initiates.
please look at my sample code:

```
<header x-data="{width: 0}">
    <div class="flex justify-between items-center py-1">
        <x-blog.search/>
        <div class="flex">
            <div><x-blog.hamburger-right/></div>
            <div class="border-l sm:border-l-2 border-gray-100 dark:border-gray-800 my-2" :resize.window="width = $el.offsetLeft"></div>
            <div><x-blog.hamburger-left/></div>
        </div>
        <x-dark-mode-switch/>
    </div>


    {{-- aside of main --}}
    <aside class="flex absolute inset-y-0 left-0 bg-gray-400 z-20" :style="`width: ${width}px;`"></aside>
    {{-- aside of blog --}}
    <aside class="absolute -right-full w-52 bg-gray-400"></aside>
</header>
```

I don't understand why that doesn't work but if there is any mistake I will be grateful if you let me know

Comment: hi, it seems like you are using tailwindcss, why don't use the class of tailwind for resize?

Comment: @BlackLotus Yes i use tailwindcss :),  because I can't use **peer** or **group** class in my case, and i should handle that with scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you try this https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-cherry-7bn7pr?file=/index.html

As stated in [documentation](https://alpinejs.dev/directives/on#window),

> When the .window modifier is present, Alpine will register the event listener on the root window object on the page instead of the element itself.

It means the `$el` will becoming to the `window` object, thus you need to use [`x-ref`](https://alpinejs.dev/directives/ref) to get the element.